# Property 'Ripple' does not exist on type 'typeof TouchableNativeFeedback'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to create a button using TouchableNativeFeedback but I ran into an error. This is my code:

```
import {TouchableNativeFeedback} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

export const Button = ({props}: Props) => {
  const [rippleColor, setRippleColor] = useState(primaryColor);
  const [rippleOverflow, setRippleOverflow] = useState(true);

  return (
    <TouchableNativeFeedback
      onPress={onPress}
      background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple(rippleColor, rippleOverflow)}
    >
      <View>{children}</View>
    </TouchableNativeFeedback> )
}
```

With this code I got this error

```
Property 'Ripple' does not exist on type 'typeof TouchableNativeFeedback'.ts(2339)
```

Anyone knows what should I do? I've tried passing the `rippleColor` & `rippleOverflow` as props and sets the type on `type Props = {}` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you using an iOS emulator?

Comment: @yudhiesh I use an Android phone (not emulator).

Comment: Is `TouchableNativeFeedback` imported?

Comment: @yudhiesh It is. It was auto-imported instantly by some extension.

Comment: Could you check that it is this `import { TouchableNativeFeedback } from "react-native";`?

Comment: @yudhiesh It (and TouchableOpacity) is actually imported from `"react-native-gesture-handler"`. My extension does the auto import. Is there any difference? Anyway, I'm gonna edit the original post to include the import line in case this is important.

Comment: Its imported that way according to the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablenativefeedback).

Comment: @yudhiesh So, I just changed it to `"react-native"` and now it works lol. Thanks!

Comment: I added an answer please approve and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You import it from `react-native` and not `react-native-gesture-handler`.

```
import { TouchableNativeFeedback } from "react-native";
```